# oMail - adding changing merge fields to vba code from database form

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, field, sendmail

I am a basic user and I've set up a command button, on click to send an email. So far, I have managed to make it work to the point where I can send an email to a particular email address but in my database, I have a stored field 'servicecontact' and want to be able to send the email to the address specified in this field.
I would also like to insert merge fields into the email body to specify who the email is relating to

This is the code I have used so far

```
Private Sub Receipt_confirmation_email_Click()
Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
Dim oMail As MailItem
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
Set oMail = oApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Select * from [Checks]", dbOpenDynaset)

oMail.Body = "RE <INSERT FIELD NAME HERE>"
oMail.Body = oMail.Body & " "
oMail.Subject = "Confirmation email"
oMail.To = {{{{THIS IS THE SECTION I AM STRUGGLING TO FORMAT}}}}
oMail.SentOnBehalfOfName = "specific@emailaddress.org"
oMail.Send
Set oMail = Nothing
Set oApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Any help you might be able to give me would be most gratefully received.

Thank you

Comment: You should be able to use a recordset, or at very least, the names on the form that creates the email. If you need more detail, please include data from the table you wish to use, or the form you wish to use.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your reply.I've included the record set, how do I format my oMail.To = field to pick up the field name called Servicecontact?

Comment: I cannot see an MS Access recordset.

Comment: I've updated my original code now, it's just the oMail.To field, which I don't understand the format I need to use to take the field from a form called 'checks' and a field name called 'servicecontact'

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to a form in code, for example:

```
oMail.To = Forms!checks!servicecontact
```

You may need to check that `servicecontact` is not null.

If the code is run on the form `checks`, then you can just use

```
 Me.servicecontact
```